# How to load Hive tables with python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I want to load my hive tables in python.

I have already tried loading using pyhive but it is giving SASL Agent error. What packages to install for that?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install:-

```
pip install sasl
pip install thrift-sasl
pip install thrift
pip install PyHive
```

Now you have to connect to **Hive**:

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="URL", port=PORT_NUMBER, username="NAME", password="YOUR_PASSWORD")
```

After having a hive connection, you can straight away run the query:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
print(cur.fetchone())
```

[For Details click here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/144487/connect-hive-running-on-remote-host-using-python-w.html)

**Note:** You can make use of connection (conn) to make a dataframe in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table", conn)
```

Comment: I am facing an issue listed below:     from pyhive import hive
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 15, in <module>
    from TCLIService import TCLIService
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 9, in <module>
    from thrift.Thrift import TType, TMessageType, TFrozenDict, TException, TApplicationException
ImportError: No module named thrift.Thrift.. is that mean I have installed pyhive correctly.. I am running this script using putty

Comment: Did you export your HADOOP_CLASSPATH? Check it out in your hadoop-env.sh file located in etc/hadoop folder.

Comment: Try to install it properly in case HADOOP_CLASSPATH is exported. Try installing pip again then above commands to install thrift again.